# Increasing --train_batch_size 2 to --train_batch_size 3 causes Mozilla DeepSpeech not to train anymore. Why?

Tags: speech-recognition, mozilla-deepspeech

Increasing `--train_batch_size 2` to `--train_batch_size 3` causes Mozilla DeepSpeech not to train anymore. What could explain this?

---

Specifically, if I run

```
./DeepSpeech.py --train_files data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-train.csv --dev_files \
 data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-dev.csv \
--test_files data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-test.csv  \
 --log_level 0 --limit_train 10000 --train_batch_size 2 --train True
```

I get `set_name: train`:

```
D Starting queue runners...
D Queue runners started.
I STARTING Optimization
D step: 77263
D epoch: 61
D target epoch: 75
D steps per epoch: 1250
D number of batches in train set: 5000
D batches per job: 4
D batches per step: 4
D number of jobs in train set: 1250
D number of jobs already trained in first epoch: 1013
D Computing Job (ID: 2, worker: 0, epoch: 61, set_name: train)...
D Starting batch...
D Finished batch step 77264.
D Sending Job (ID: 2, worker: 0, epoch: 61, set_name: train)...
D Computing Job (ID: 3, worker: 0, epoch: 61, set_name: train)...
D Starting batch...
D Finished batch step 77265.
D Sending Job (ID: 3, worker: 0, epoch: 61, set_name: train)...
D Computing Job (ID: 4, worker: 0, epoch: 61, set_name: train)...
D Starting batch...
D Finished batch step 77266.
D Sending Job (ID: 4, worker: 0, epoch: 61, set_name: train)...
[...]
```

However, if I run:

```
./DeepSpeech.py --train_files data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-train.csv --dev_files \
 data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-dev.csv \
--test_files data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-test.csv  \
 --log_level 0 --limit_train 10000 --train_batch_size 3 --train True
```

I get `set_name: test`:

```
D Starting queue runners...
D Queue runners started.
D step: 77263
D epoch: 92
D target epoch: 75
D steps per epoch: 833
D number of batches in train set: 3334
D batches per job: 4
D batches per step: 4
D number of jobs in train set: 833
D number of jobs already trained in first epoch: 627
D Computing Job (ID: 2, worker: 0, epoch: 92, set_name: test)...
D Starting batch...
D Finished batch step 77263.
D Sending Job (ID: 2, worker: 0, epoch: 92, set_name: test)...
D Computing Job (ID: 3, worker: 0, epoch: 92, set_name: test)...
D Starting batch...
D Finished batch step 77263.
D Sending Job (ID: 3, worker: 0, epoch: 92, set_name: test)...
D Computing Job (ID: 4, worker: 0, epoch: 92, set_name: test)...
D Starting batch...
D Finished batch step 77263.
D Sending Job (ID: 4, worker: 0, epoch: 92, set_name: test)...
D Computing Job (ID: 5, worker: 0, epoch: 92, set_name: test)...
D Starting batch...
D Finished batch step 77263.
D Sending Job (ID: 5, worker: 0, epoch: 92, set_name: test)...
[...]
```

I train Mozilla DeepSpeech using 4 Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as pointed out by
[lissyx](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/increasing-train-batch-size-2-to-train-batch-size-3-causes-deepspeech-not-to-train-anymore-why/29790/4?u=franck_dernoncourt), was that the checkpoint directory wasn't cleaned up. This was apparent in the log in the question details, e.g. `D Finished batch step 77263.`, whereas if the checkpoint directory is cleaned up, the batch step should be `0`. As a result, when running with `--train_batch_size > 2`, it was directly jumping to the test phase.

The default location of the the checkpoint directory on Ubuntu is: `/home/[username]/.local/share/deepspeech/checkpoints`. One can change the checkpoint location with the `--checkpoint_dir` argument.